# How to trigger tooltip display on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have used the `{onmouseover}` variable for the `<a>` tag which calls the script function on `hover`.
As follows:

`<a class="tooltip" href="#" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, '#tip3', {sticky:true, position:0, cssClass:'no-padding'})">Lorem, ipsum.</a>`

For desktop pages, this is not a problem, but for mobile pages, this is no longer practical.

I want the `{onmouseover}` variable to change to `{onclick}` for mobile size `(less than 768px)`.

Is this applicable or not?

If it is applicable, please give me the code of this issue.

Many thanks.

Comment: The keyword 'this' will refer to window. Where is tooltip object defined?

Comment: Hello. The `tooltip` object is defined in a separate script. My problem is only converting `{onmouseover}` to `{onclick}` in size less than 768px.

Comment: At first place, ask yourself how the anchor codes got there in the HTML. And once you figure out where and how you injected the code, then put some condition to display another anchor with `onclick` instead when size is mobile. Because the solution depends on how the anchor code got there. Or if you can only check it on load at client side, then you can listen to onready event and select the anchor and manually add `onclick` attribute and remove `mouseover` if you want too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mouse interactions there is the [MouseOver event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp), which you’re already using. For touch screens there is the [TouchStart event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_touchstart.asp). To achieve what you want you’ll probably have to use both of these. You can point both these event handlers to the same function.

Comment: Hello. Thank you. This variable solved my problem to a large extent.